# Removing mean from data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I used the following code to remove the mean from my timeseries dataset that has 3 independent features and 1 dependent feature

```
mean = np.mean((df.values), axis=-1, keepdims=True)
df = df - mean
```

But this is taking the mean of the row and not column. Is there a reason for this ? Because I thought -1 indicates it should take the mean of the column? Or is it because it’s time dependent ?

Example of dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'date': [1988, 1989, 1990, 1991],
'value1': [1265, 4349, 5589, 3340],
'value2': [155, 552, 958, 280],
'value3': [55, 13, 95, 80],
'value4': [0.55, 0.12, 0.80, 0.22]
}) 
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
```

Comment: This is a pure `numpy` and `pandas` question, and it has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to `axis=0` then it will give you the mean of your "column".

**Explanation**
Just plot your data frame and you will see how it actually is structured:

```
>>> df
      value1  value2  value3  value4
date                                
1988    1265     155      55    0.55
1989    4349     552      13    0.12
1990    5589     958      95    0.80
1991    3340     280      80    0.22
```

[image]
So now you see why you have to set `axis = 0`

By the way there is no need to call numpy. Pandas has mean built in:

```
>>> df.mean()
value1    3635.7500
value2     486.2500
value3      60.7500
value4       0.4225
dtype: float64
```

Note I didn't explicitly set `axis=0` because it's the default.

Comment: Is there a reason row mean is the default? Should I actually be taking the row mean and not the column mean when I want to detrend?